# Magento 2 How to remove tax from checkout?

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, cart, onepage-checkout, tax

I'd like to remove `tax` from `cart` and `checkout`.
Now it shows `0` or "`Not yet calculated`" text.

I've already remove estimated shipping and tax by comment out code from
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/shipping.phtml`
but i just cant find this section.

In my admin panel all options under Tax is set to "`No`" or "`Excluding Tax`"

Answer (score 19):

If you want to leave taxes enabled and with a value but just remove them from display remove the item with the name `tax` at the appropriate place.

For example to remove tax from the checkout cart sidebar add this to your themes (or module) `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

To remove from cart you would add this to `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Excellent! just I think you could label these clearer, the second block is for the checkout page sidebar first for the basket page cart

Answer (score 1):

Login to your magento admin panel.
Go, Stores > (under Taxes) > Tax zones and rates > click your tax options > then put the Rate percentage to 0.

Also don't forget to Clear your cache, Remove the products form card, go back to homepage, add product again, go to checkout and see.

This should remove the tax completely from the checkout. I've check it, it works for me.