# Remove tax from Cart

Tags: magento-2.1, tax, shopping-cart

I am using `aloquick` theme. I would like to remove `tax` from `cart`. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158233/magento-2-how-to-remove-tax-from-checkout

Comment: there is option I. admin to remove tax from cart. another way to remove through XML too. You need to check from admin first.

Comment: Thanks @Jai for your reply. I tried from Admin but failed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Override a tax module to remove tax from cart page

create `checkout_cart_index.xml` in following path

```
\app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Tax\layout
```

Paste the following code in `checkout_cart_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ranganathan.s for your reply.  I have no such location `\app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Tax\layout`.  

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1CAA.png

Comment: vendor/theme refers your vendor name and theme name...use this location....\app\design\frontend\Alothemes\default\Magento_Tax\layout

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think my theme is `Alothemes`. But what is `Vendor`? Thanks

Comment: As your screenshot `Alothemes ` is vendor and `default` is theme..